# How to disable Future date in DatePicker in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, calendar

I am using DatePickerDialog in my Android project using Kotlin. I have successfully created DatePickerDialog and its working fine.
     Now I want to give some validation like in DatePickerDialog I want to disable future date.
For Example, Today date is 22 Aug 2019 I want to disable all date after today date.

I tried to use `dateSetListener.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis())`

but it's not working

````java
var cal = Calendar.getInstance()

      // create an OnDateSetListener

        val dateSetListener = object : DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        override fun onDateSet(
            view: DatePicker, year: Int, monthOfYear: Int,
            dayOfMonth: Int
        ) {
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
            updateDateInView()

        }

       // dateSetListener.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    }

    // when you click on the button, show DatePickerDialog that is set with OnDateSetListener
    button_date!!.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(view: View) {

            DatePickerDialog(this@MainActivity,
                dateSetListener,
                // set DatePickerDialog to point to today's date when it loads up
                cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show()
            }
    })```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var dialog = DatePickerDialog(
                this@MainActivity,dateSetListener,
                // set DatePickerDialog to point to today's date when it loads up
                cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            )

            dialog.datePicker.maxDate = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis
            dialog.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, @Furqan Khan it's Working fine.